# How would i go about saving drag and drop items to a form variable and sending it through email?

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, forms

Here is the setup: http://sawhost.com/saw/demo.html

I am wanting visitors to drag and drop 6 of the magazines into the boxes on top, and when they hit submit, i want at least the title attribute for each magazine image to be added to a form element or something...

I have a hidden text area on the form ready to receive, but im sure its a small bit of code im overlooking thats not making it work. here is a copy of the javascript i have so far.

```
function checkEmail(myForm) {

  var coices = new Array();
  var input = "";
  choice[0] = document.getElementById("box12").innerHTML + "<br />";
  choice[1] = document.getElementById("box102").innerHTML + "<br />";
  choice[2] = document.getElementById("box103").innerHTML + "<br />";
  choice[3] = document.getElementById("box104").innerHTML + "<br />";
  choice[4] = document.getElementById("box105").innerHTML + "<br />";
  choice[5] = document.getElementById("box106").innerHTML + "<br />";

  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    input += choice[i];
  }
  myForm.list.value = input;

  return (true);
}
```

Comment: Since you're loading jQuery why not use it for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function checkEmail(myForm) {
    var choice = [],
        input  = '', i;

    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        input += document.getElementById("box10" + (i+1)).getElementsByTagName('img')[0].title + '<br />';
    }

    myForm.list.value = input;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: this worked like a charm! thanks for the tip, forgot about the byTagName =P